# why i can't use the smart-pointer to make a new QLineEdit class

Tags: c++, qt5, smart-pointers

As the title demonstrates, i want to use some buffer for QLineEdit class by smart-pointer, but the compiler show "invaild application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'QLineEdit'". I found the 'aligned_buffer.h' file by buiding message. but it is helpless. What i'm confused about is when i use the same way to use some buffer for QTextEdit, the compiler is successful. why QLineEdit can't use same way to do that?

```
...
shared_ptr<QTextEdit> t1 = make_shared<QTextEdit>(); // successd
shared_ptr<QLineEdit> t2 = make_shared<QLineEdit>(); // failed
...
```

Comment: Maybe you forgot to include `QLineEdit` header?

Comment: `...to incomplete type 'QLineEdit'` - clear indication the compiler hasn't a clue what a QLineEdit is at the time of compiling that line of source. So.. figure out why. Missing header? Conditionally excluded by preprocessor? There could be any number of reasons that we could only guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the header files correctly

```
#include <QTextEdit> // https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html
#include <QLineEdit> // https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html
#include <memory>     //https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared

int main(){
   shared_ptr<QTextEdit> t1 = std::make_shared<QTextEdit>(); 
   shared_ptr<QLineEdit> t2 = std::make_shared<QLineEdit>(); 
}
```